# Textbox transparent like a hole on my winform

Tags: textbox, transparent

So I've got a C# winform, with a panel and a textbox belonging to the panel.

The problem is that the textbox appears as a hole on my winform. I can see what's behind it (my desktop, other windows etc). That sounds like a bug to me since, after some google research, I came to the conclusion that textboxes cannot be transparent.

In case any of the following is relevant: winform transparency key is set to transparent, textbox `backcolor=white` and `forecolor=black`.

I tried to restart both the visual studio and the computer but the problem persists.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: can you post the code? another thing, transparency other than Form.Opacity has horrible performance in winforms. i wouldnt recommend it

Comment: Do you need the auto generated designer code? I haven't coded anything else. I just dropped a few controls on a winform...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Color.Transparent is 0,255,255,255 in ARGB. that means its white with no opacity. since the transparency key is for non-transparent colors (24Bit RGB) it doesnt use the Alpha part. That means. Color.Transparent == Color.White for the TransparencyKey

So the behaviour you are having is 100% expected, TransparencyKey is white, and TextBox BackColor is white. Therefor the textbox Background is not visible. not a bug at all.

You can fix this by not setting the TransparencyKey at all, or setting it to Color.Empty or some other Color. Or you can change the BackgroundColor of the TextBox if you want to keep white as the TransparencyKey.

Having White as TransparencyKey is not a good idea though (u have seen why). i would recommend using Cyan or Magenta (rarely used colors) if you still want to use it

Comment: I removed the transparency setting from the code and it works OK... it's still strange though because I didn't change anything in the first place. I just arranged the controls on the winform and I had this problem! Thanks.